# sql failed jobs export to csv with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am battling with a PowerShell script that captures all SQL Failed jobs for the past day and exports it to .CSV

Please view code below.

```html
param (
 #[string]$serverInstance = '03RNB-VSQLPRD4\SQLPRD04

)

begin {
 [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
}
process {
 try {
  Write-Verbose "List failed SQL Server jobs using SMO..."

        $serverInstance = Get-Content "C:\MountSpaceCollector\SQLJobFailures\servers2.txt";
  $server = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.server $serverInstance

  $results = @()
  $reasons = @()

  $jobs = $server.jobserver.jobs | where-object {$_.isenabled}

  # Process all SQL Agent Jobs looking for failed jobs based on the last run outcome
  foreach ($job in $jobs) {
   [int]$outcome = 0
   [string]$reason = ""

   # Did the job fail completely?
   if ($job.LastRunOutcome -eq "Failed") {
    $outcome++
    $reasons += "Job failed: " + $job.name + " Result: " + $job.LastRunOutcome 

    # Did any of the steps fail?
    foreach ($jobStep in $job.jobsteps) {

     if ($jobStep.LastRunOutcome -ne "Succeeded") {
      $outcome++
      $reasons += "Step failed: " + $jobStep.name + " Result: " + $jobStep.LastRunOutcome 
     }
    }
   }

   if ($outcome -gt 0) {
    $jobFailure = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
     Name = $job.name 
     LastRunDate = $job.lastrundate
     LastRunOutcome = $reasons
    }
    $results += $jobFailure 
   }
  }

  Write-Output $results | Export-CSV -Path 'C:\MountSpaceCollector\SQLJobFailures\SQLJobFailures.csv' -Delimiter '|'
 }
 catch [Exception] {
  Write-Error $Error[0] 
  $err = $_.Exception
  while ( $err.InnerException ) {
   $err = $err.InnerException
   Write-Output $err.Message 
Write-Output $results 

  }  
 }
}
```

But It Exports all except the last field (LastRunOutcome).  It only displays "System.Object[]"?

Can anyone please assist with this as I do not know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's because $Reasons is an object, more specifically an array. You need to format the reasons differently, as a string for instance, to be able to have it appear in the CSV normally.

Perhaps you meant to use the string $Reason that you declare, but don't use?